# C pointer char to lowercase

Tags: c, char

I have pointer array and I want to lowerCase, how I can do this?

```
char *myPointer = "HELLO MY NAME IS POINTER";

for(....)
    myPointer[i] = tolower(myPointer[i]);
```

Crashed my application.
I need use pointer!

Thank you

Comment: You can't use your `myPointer` for that: it points to read-only memory. (Or more correctly: it points to memory that, when it is written to causes undefined behaviour). If you change it to an array you can do it: `char myPointer[] = "HELLO MY NAME IS POINTER";`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [tolower](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cctype/tolower/), which returns a lowercase version of the given character.

```
char* myPointer = "OH MY HOST";

const int length = strlen( myPointer ); // get the length of the text
char* lower = ( char* )malloc( length + 1 ); // allocate 'length' bytes + 1 (for null terminator) and cast to char*
lower[ length ] = 0; // set the last byte to a null terminator

// copy all character bytes to the new buffer using tolower
for( int i = 0; i < length; i++ )
{
    lower[ i ] = tolower( myPointer[ i ] );
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but

char* lower = new char[ strlen( myPointer ) ];

there is some syntax problem, i dont now where..?

Comment: @JaLe29: William used C++ syntax here, while your question was about C. This is one of the differences.

Comment: Sorry for the C++ syntax. I'll change it to C if you need it.

Answer (score 4):

`myPointer` points to a string literal, modifying it is [**undefined behaviour**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). You can use an array instead if you want to be able to modify it:

```
char myPointer[]= "HELLO MY NAME IS POINTER";
```